# How set a region using CLCircularRegion SWIFT? Geofencing

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, latitude-longitude

I'm working with `CoreLocation` on SWIFT and I want to create a geographical region, where I can be able to see if the user is in the correct place. Example if the user is at this coordinate: `Lat: 44.8856828 and Lon: -93.2131653`. I want to set a region of `200` meters around him to secure the data is correct and the user can be able to check in any part of the place with the `200-meter` region. This is what I have to far in my code!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    latLabel.text = latStore
    lonLabel.text = lonStore
    readData()
    regionLocation()
}

//Accessing the are around the user

func regionLocation() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("You enter the place")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("Your exit the place")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
    print("Start monitoring")
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    let currentRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!, radius: 200, identifier: "Place")
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: currentRegion)
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is correct, what problems are you facing? Also please post your code as code/text and not as image.

Comment: @lorenzoliveto in my code when I change the location is not displaying in the console that the user has left the perimeter of 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually start monitoring anywhere.  You request authorization, but don't actually handle the success (or failure!) of that request.

You could (partially) do that by monitoring for authorization success:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if(status == .authorizedAlways) {
        let currentRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!, radius: 200, identifier: "Place")
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: currentRegion)
    }
}
```

But that doesn't handle the case where you already have authorization.  You really should be checking the current authorization state before requesting authorization.

You also really don't want to request authorization from within `didStartMonitoring` and calling `startMonitoring` from within `didStartMonitoring` could quickly lead to insanity :)